# Phalcon routing - making route segments optional

Tags: routes, phalcon

I have the following route added to `Phalcon\MVC\Router`:

```
$router = new Phalcon\Mvc\Router();

$router->removeExtraSlashes(true)
    ->setDefaultNamespace('My\Controllers')
    ->setDefaultModule('default')
    ->setDefaultController('index')
    ->setDefaultAction('index');

$router->add('/admin/:controller/:action/:params', [
    'module' => 'admin',
    'controller' => 1,
    'action' => 2,
    'params' => 3,
    'namespace' => 'My\Admin\Controllers'
])->setName('admin_module');
```

I'm handling the following URLs:

1. `/admin/foo/bar/baz` - works good. I get `admin` module, `foo` controller, `bar` action, `"baz"` parameter.
2. `/admin/foo/bar` - works good. I get `admin` module, `foo` controller, `bar` action.
3. `/admin/foo` - **does not match**. I expect to get `admin` module, `foo` controller, `index` action.
4. `/admin` - **does not match**. I expect to get `admin` module, `index` controller, `index` action.

The question:

How can I make route segments optional and default to provided default values of controller and action name. I would like to avoid defining extra routes for `/admin` and `/admin/:controller`.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Most common way to make this works is to add each pattern to `Router` as custom `Route` with same `paths` options (the second argument in `Route::add()`).
As for annotation routes its good to choose few `@Route` directives for `Action` methods.
This way is majored for usage cause convenient `URL` generation by `Route` (route name) will be faster then universal one.

regards

Comment: thanks! I just learned phalcon few days ago and I dont realize that you can also use annotation to perform route (i though annotation only for defining field type in model).